# I want a direction of a vector which is 90 degree angled towards a point

Tags: math

I'm trying to find the shortest distance to travel so that a LineSkillShot,LS-(a vector in 2d plane) hits the target(x,y) in fastest way possible. I know my position and the enemys position, I also know the start and the end of the LineSkillShot vector and the angle between the start of LS(my position) and TP.

So what I'm looking for is the Distance from LineSkillshot to target position(with 90 angle), and the direction that i should move. [image]

Comment: what did you try so far? if you have a vector (x,y), then (y, -x) is a vector perpendicular to it.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think this is directly related to C# but purely a math question and so off-topic for SO.

Comment: No, what Ronald says is, say LS is (5,2) then your result direction is (2,-5). Which is a 90° angle, but 180° wrong direction.

Comment: So what you are saying is my directions should be(SL.Y, -SL.X) for 0<⍺<90 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need is something like this:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Input Data
        var myPosition = new Vector(x:0, y:0);
        var targetPosition = new Vector(x: 1, y: 2);
        var SkillShotLine = Vector.fromPolar(angle: Math.PI /((double)6), radius: 1);
        
        //Calculations
        var myPosToTgt = Vector.add(v2: targetPosition, v1: myPosition.getNegative()); //Vector from myPosition to targetPosition
        var projOnSL = Vector.calcProjection(projectThisVector: myPosToTgt, onThisVector: SkillShotLine); //Vector projection myPosToTgt on SkillShotLine
        var distV = Vector.add(v2: projOnSL, v1: myPosToTgt.getNegative()); //Distance vector
        
        Console.WriteLine("myPosition:" + myPosition.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("targetPosition" + targetPosition.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("SkillShotLine:" + SkillShotLine.ToString());
        
        Console.WriteLine("Distance:" + distV.magnitude);
        
    }
    
    internal class Vector {
        private double _x;
        private double _y;
        
        public Vector(double x, double y){
            this._x = x;
            this._y = y;
        }
        
        public double x {
            get => this._x;
        }
        
        public double y {
            get => this._x;
        }
        
        public double magnitude {
            get {
                return Math.Sqrt(this._x*this._x + this._y*this._y);
            }
        }
        
        public double angle {
            get  {
                return Math.Atan2(this._y, this._x);
            }
        }
        
        public Vector getNegative(){
            return new Vector(-this._x, -this._y);
        }
        
        public static Vector getNegative(Vector v){
            return v.getNegative();
        }
        
        public static double dotProduct(Vector v1, Vector v2){
            return ((double)v1._x*(double)v2._x) + ((double)v1._y*(double)v2._y);
        }
        
        public static Vector fromPolar(double angle, double radius) {
            
            return new Vector(x: radius*Math.Cos(angle), y: radius * Math.Sin(angle));
        }
        
        public static Vector scalarProduct(double m, Vector v){
            return new Vector(x: (m*v._x) , y: (m*v._y));
        }
        
        public static Vector getUnitary(Vector v){
            var m = v.magnitude;
            return Vector.scalarProduct(m: (1/m), v: v);
        }
        
        public static Vector calcProjection(Vector projectThisVector, Vector onThisVector) {
            var m = Vector.dotProduct(v1: projectThisVector, v2: onThisVector)    / onThisVector.magnitude;
            return Vector.scalarProduct(m: m, v: Vector.getUnitary(onThisVector));
        }
    
        public override string ToString() {
            return string.Format("(x:{0},y:{1}) (angle:{2},radius:{3})", this._x, this._y, this.angle, this.magnitude);
        }
        
        public static Vector add(Vector v1, Vector v2){
            return new Vector(x: (v1._x + v2._x), y: (v1._y + v2._y));
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The code above uses (0,0) as MyPosition, (1,2) as TargetPosition and SkillShotLine as unitary vector pointin to 30 degrees (PI/6 in radians)

The example calculates the vector distV as the perpendicular vector from TargetPosition to the line defined by SkillShotLine as follows:

- Calcs on myPotToTgt the vector from MyPostion to TargetPosition
- Calcs on projOnSL this vector (myPotToTgt) projection on the unitary vector SkillShotLine
- Calcs on distV the vector from TargetPosition to the point projOnSL

[image: Vectors used in the example]

x

Comment: So I tried this code, but not sure which function to use, i used var distV  and moved my player accordenly, distV.x and distV.y, but it went into buttom of the screen, i have provided the necessary information on myPostion and targetPosition, however i didnt understand the data you needed in SkillShotLine.

Comment: SkillShotLine is a unitary vector ponting the direction you like. In the code i posted SkillShotLine is  instanced as a unitary vector (radius:1) pointing to a PI/6 angle from the posive x-axis